# Node can´t start react index.js Exit 1

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

Today i tried to start my react Project, but i seems like npm cant find my index.js
Yesterday it worked perfectly fine. I already deleted the npm cache and reinstalled the node modules. In my package.json is the right path to the index.js as scripts : start.

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! ride@0.1.0 start: `./src/index.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the ride@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\benit\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-09-08T13_04_57_433Z-debug.log
```

I also looked up my backlog file but did not get any information from it.

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.5
3 info using node@v12.18.2
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle ride@0.1.0~prestart: ride@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle ride@0.1.0~start: ride@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle ride@0.1.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle ride@0.1.0~start: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\benit\Documents\TagProject\RiderTag\react\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Files\cpp\bin\Intel64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Files\cpp\bin\ia32;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\ia32\compiler;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\intel64\compiler;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;c:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Adobe\AGL;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\benit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts;C:\Users\benit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\;C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.8.0_171\bin;C:\Users\benit\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Users\benit\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\benit\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox;C:\Users\C:\Users\benit\Documents\GitHub\spotify_boost\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe;C:\src\flutter\bin;C:\Users\benit\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\heroku\bin
9 verbose lifecycle ride@0.1.0~start: CWD: C:\Users\benit\Documents\TagProject\RiderTag\react
10 silly lifecycle ride@0.1.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', './src/index.js' ]
11 silly lifecycle ride@0.1.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle ride@0.1.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: ride@0.1.0 start: `./src/index.js`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
14 verbose pkgid ride@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\benit\Documents\TagProject\RiderTag\react\src
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18362
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
18 verbose node v12.18.2
19 verbose npm  v6.14.5
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error ride@0.1.0 start: `./src/index.js`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the ride@0.1.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "ride",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@auth0/auth0-react": "^1.0.0",
    "@date-io/date-fns": "^1.3.13",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.14.0",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.11",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "date-fns": "^2.0.0-beta.5",
    "fontawesome": "^5.6.3",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "reactstrap": "^8.5.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "./src/index.js",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@material-ui/pickers": "^3.2.10"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000"
}
```

Comment: Does `yarn start` work?

Comment: Hey! Please provide the source code of the `package.json` file. And it would be also fine to see the output of the following command: `tree -I node_modules` to get a bit more context (that's the example for Linux, but hopefully it will be somehow similar to Windows).

Comment: @PrateekThapa i dont use yarn, so it wont work.

Answer (score 0):

Add "start": "react-scripts start" instead of "start": "./src/index.js",

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't know your project structure, I assume that you're building your app with create-react-app CLI.
Replace your "start" script with the following line:

```
"start": "cd packages/react-scripts && node bin/react-scripts.js start"
```